# Review Audit Detector

Tags: script, api-v2.2, review

Motivated by the question [Would a userscript to determine whether a review is an audit be illegal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310885), I wrote a userscript for this purpose. The algorithm is as follows:

If the post score shown in review is 0, the script checks its real score using the API. If the score is greater than 1, the post is a known-good audit. If the score is less than -1, or the post does not exist, it is a known-bad audit.

The difference of 1 vote is not considered conclusive, since there is a remote possibility of someone up/down voting the post in just the right time. The known-good  audits actually have score 5 or higher, and known bad (it seems) have score -2 or less.

The audits are indicated by the color of the review bar.

Known bad audit:

[image: bad]

Known good audit:

[image]

The logic of suggested edit audits is different; the script is not tested in that queue, but probably fails to detect audits accurately.

[Source on GitHub](https://github.com/normalhuman/AuditDetector)

Comment: Does one install this as a native extension, or on a userscript manager like  Greasemonkey?

Comment: I've run into a bug in the close queue. The first review was a good audit which was correctly identified, but after clicking "Leave Open" the bar stayed green on the next review (which wasn't an audit). I refreshed and the bar was normal again, but later the script failed to detect [this audit](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/543796).

Comment: script removed from GitHub 